# Eclipse SVN Synchronze workspace error - Updating Synchronize view for SVN Workspace - java/nio/file/Paths

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I updated the Eclipse SVN plugins today and after that I can't sync my workspace with SVN repository.
I am using java 1.6. I tried with java 1.7 as well. still I'm getting following error in eclipse.

An internal error occurred during: "Updating Synchronize view for SVN Workspace.".
java/nio/file/Paths.

> SVN: '0x00000025: Send Notifications' operation finished with error:
>   java/nio/file/Paths

This issue came only after updating the svn plugin. I'm using SVNKit 1.7.13 svn connector.

Any idea how to solve this??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a work around for this.
Uninstalled all svn plugins from Eclipse and restarted it.
Installed Subclipse svn plugin from http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error when I opened Eclipse. Checking the file: workspase-path/.metadata/.log I found the following exception:

```
!MESSAGE SVN: 'SVN Decorator' operation finished with error: java/nio/file/Paths
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/Paths
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility.getNodeKind(SVNUtility.java:1145)
...
```

To solve the problem **I installed JRE 1.7**, then I changed eclipse.ini to force Eclipse to use it, adding the next at the beginning:

```
-jv
"path-to-jre7/bin/javaw.exe"
```

Comment: but I want to use JRE 1.6

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Luna on Win 7 64 bit with the 2.0.3 subversive team provider and the Polarion SVNKit 1.8.7 version 4.1.2. Clearly somewhere in these java 7 is needed. Servaq's suggestion improved things for me but didn't quite fix everything. But a similar change to eclipse.ini did the trick for me: I added

```
-vm  
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

right before the -vmargs. Obviously, the path to server\jvm.dll is installation-dependent.

Just in case it's helpful to Chandika  ("I wants to use java 1.6"),
I'm still using java 6 as the compiler/runtime for the code I'm developing within this eclipse. I'm just using java 7 to start eclipse.